# Lorentzian scipy.optimize.leastsq fit to data fails

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares, data-fitting

Since I took a lecture on Python I wanted to use it to fit my data. Although I have been trying for a while now, I still have no idea why this is not working.

### What I would like to do

Take one data-file after another from a subfolder (here called: 'Test'), transform the data a little bit and fit it with a Lorentzian function.

### Problem description

When I run the code posted below, it does not fit anything and just returns my initial parameters after 4 function calls. I tried scaling the data, playing around with `ftol` and `maxfev` after checking the python documentation over and over again, but nothing improved. I also tried changing the lists to `numpy.arrays` explicitely, as well as the solution given to the question [scipy.optimize.leastsq returns best guess parameters not new best fit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12473406/2062965), `x = x.astype(np.float64)`. No improvement. Strangely enough, for few selected data-files this same code worked at some point, but for the majority it never did. It can definitely be fitted, since a Levenberg-Marquard fitting routine gives reasonably good results in Origin.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong or point out alternatives...?

```
import numpy,math,scipy,pylab
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import glob,os
for files in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    x=[]
    y=[]
    z=[]
    f = open(files, 'r')
    raw=f.readlines()
    f.close()
    del raw[0:8]       #delete Header
    for columns in ( raw2.strip().split() for raw2 in raw ):  #data columns
        x.append(float(columns[0]))
        y.append(float(columns[1]))
        z.append(10**(float(columns[1])*0.1)) #transform data for the fit
    def lorentz(p,x):
        return (1/(1+(x/p[0] - 1)**4*p[1]**2))*p[2]
    def errorfunc(p,x,z):
        return lorentz(p,x)-z

    p0=[3.,10000.,0.001]

    Params,cov_x,infodict,mesg,ier = leastsq(errorfunc,p0,args=(x,z),full_output=True)
    print Params
    print ier
```

Comment: try reading your input `.txt` using `numpy.loadtxt()`, and then check if the values of x, y, and z are making sense...

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing your data it is hard to tell what is going wrong. I generated some random noise and used your code to perform a fit to it. Everything works okay. This algorithm does not allow for parameter boundaries so you may run into problems if your `p0` is close to zero. I did the following:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lorentz(p,x):
    return p[2] / (1.0 + (x / p[0] - 1.0)**4 * p[1]**2)

def errorfunc(p,x,z):
        return lorentz(p,x)-z

p = np.array([0.5, 0.25, 1.0], dtype=np.double)
x = np.linspace(-1.5, 2.5, num=30, endpoint=True)
noise = np.random.randn(30) * 0.05
z = lorentz(p,x)
noisyz = z + noise

p0 = np.array([-2.0, -4.0, 6.8], dtype=np.double) #Initial guess
solp, ier = leastsq(errorfunc, 
                    p0, 
                    args=(x,noisyz),
                    Dfun=None,
                    full_output=False,
                    ftol=1e-9,
                    xtol=1e-9,
                    maxfev=100000,
                    epsfcn=1e-10,
                    factor=0.1)

plt.plot(x, z, 'k-', linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.6, label='Theoretical')
plt.scatter(x, noisyz, c='r', marker='+', color='r', label='Measured Data')
plt.plot(x, lorentz(solp,x), 'g--', linewidth=2, label='leastsq fit')
plt.xlim((-1.5, 2.5))
plt.ylim((0.0, 1.2))
plt.grid(which='major')
plt.legend(loc=8)
plt.show()
```

This yielded a solution of:
`solp = array([ 0.51779002,  0.26727697,  1.02946179])`
Which is close to the theoretical value:
`np.array([0.5, 0.25, 1.0])`
[image]

Comment: Where does this Lorentzian function come from?